# How to make a Button Checked/Unchecked with another Button?

Tags: java, android, button, state, imagebutton

I am trying to create a **image button (Btn1) that changes its state on "unchecked" when I click another button (Btn2).** I already tried to do it with a boolean but the button state didn't change when the boolean changed. I have heard about the "setChecked" method but I couldn't find how how to use it...

Thanks for your answer in advance.

```
imageButton_info = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton_info);
    imageButton_info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){...
```

Comment: [setChecked(true/false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setChecked%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `RadioButton` instead of `ImageButton`.You can design your own selector to show the background depends on whether it is checked. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`ImageButton` has no `setChecked(...)` method. It is a method of `ToggleButton` You can use `ToggleButton` like this

```
final ToggleButton button1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
final ToggleButton button2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);

button1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                button2.setChecked(!b);
        }
});
button2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            button1.setChecked(!b);
        }
});
```

Anyway, `RadioButton` is best suited in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use on of the following instead of ImageButton.

- Radio button
- Switch
- Checkboxes